# Laravel with Dropzonejs is Not Passing through Success Callback

Tags: laravel, dropzone.js

For some reason, when I upload images on my dropzone, it does not go to the success callback.

This is my goal, I want a variable called "counter" to increment everytime the upload is successful via the success callback but because it's not going to the success callback, I can't increment the "counter" variable.

Here are my codes:

***Inside my Blade file***

```
    <form action="{{ route('media.store') }}" class="dropzone" id="mediaDropzone" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
        <div class="fallback">
           <input type="file" name="file" id="" multiple>
        </div>
    </form>
```

***Inside my scripts section***

```
    Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
    $("#mediaDropzone").dropzone();

    var items_counter = 0;
    $('#counter').text(items_counter + " items");

    Dropzone.options.mediaDropzone = {
        uploadMultiple: true,
        parallelUploads: 2,
        maxFilesize: 16,
        acceptedFiles: ".png, .jpg, .gif, .jpeg, .mp4, .webm",
        headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content') },
        previewTemplate: document.querySelector('#preview').innerHTML,
        success: function (file, response) {
            items_counter++;
            $("#counter").text(items_counter);
        },
        error: function(err){
            console.log(err);
        },
        init: function(){
            this.on("success", function (file, response){
                items_counter++;
                $("#counter").text(items_counter);
            })
        }
    };
```

*** Inside my controller file ***

```
    public function store(Request $request)
{
    $images = $request->file('file');

    if(!is_array($images)) {
        $images = [$images];
    }

    if(!is_dir('storage/uploads/images')) {
        mkdir('storage/uploads/images', 0777);
    }

    for($i = 0; $i < count($images); $i++) {
        $image = $images[$i];
        $date = new DateTime();
        $filename = pathinfo($request->file('file')->getClientOriginalName(), PATHINFO_FILENAME);
        $save_name = $filename . '_' . $date->format('Y-m-d') . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();

        $image->move('storage/uploads/images', $save_name);

        $uploadImage = new Media;
        $uploadImage->file_name = $save_name;
        $uploadImage->file_type = $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $uploadImage->save();
    }
    return Response::json([
        'message' => 'Image Saved Successfully!'
    ], 200);
}
```

Please help me understand or figure out why my success callback is not firing.

Comment: are you sure that images uploaded well ?

Comment: Yes, 100% sure.